# Registered email does not allow updating user data

Tags: php, mysqli

When I log in to the system, I call the email address using the following variable `$email`

It should be noted that this email is already verified, it is the only email in the system, there are no duplicates.

Now in the configuration of the account, the user can update his data including his email address.

The problem:

If the user changes his name, address, telephone but less mail, the system sends me the following personalized message:

**The user with this email already exists!**

It's your same email should not throw me that error, and should allow you to update your data but it does not.

I did the following

```
$stmtEmail = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND id_user NOT IN (?)");
$stmtEmail->bind_param("ss",$email,$email);
```

but it throws me error in the `$stmtEmail->bind_param("ss",$email,$email);`

My code:

```
$stmtEmail = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
$stmtEmail->bind_param("s",$email);
$stmtEmail->execute();
$stmtEmail->store_result();

if ($stmtEmail->num_rows>0) {
    echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["email" =>"The user with this email already exists!"]]);
    exit;
} else {
    $stmtUpAccounts = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET first_name=?, last_name=?, phone=?, country=?, city=?, state=?, address=?, zip_code=?, email=? WHERE id_user=?");
    $stmtUpAccounts->bind_param("sssssssssi", $Ufirst_name,$Ulast_name,$Uphone,$Ucountry,$Ucity,$Ustate,$Uaddress,$Uzip_code,$Uemail,$id_user);
    if ($stmtUpAccounts->execute()) {
        echo json_encode(['status'=> true, 'message'=>"Your data was updated correctly"]);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"We are sorry, but we can not process your request. Try again later."]);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: So.. what's the issue?

Comment: Not sure what you want here. Describe the situation more clearly.

Comment: @CodeThing  It does not allow me to update the data leaving your same mail

Comment: How you are recognizing users. The user who is updating is logged in?

Comment: @CodeThing Obviously the data can only be edited if the user has logged in, so I indicated that this variable $ email has the current registered mail.

Comment: @CodeThing I did the following `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND id_user NO IN (?)` $stmtEmail->bind_param("ss",$email,$email); but it throws me an error in the bind_param

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Edit my question, excuse me now is my problem better silver or not?

Comment: Can you try using this.
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND id_user!=?`
`$stmtEmail->bind_param("sd",$email,$loggedInUserID);`

Comment: @CodeThing It does not work, enter an email from another user and the system will let you save this data and that should not happen, because that email is already registered by another user, that data record should be given only if it is your same mail or if it is another email that is not registered.

Comment: @Pepe What about we validate email address as well as user id
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND id_user=?`
and then allow to update data only when this comes true `$stmtEmail->num_rows>0`

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you have all the userdata on hand,

When checking the email modify your query

```
$stmtEmail = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND id != ?");
$stmtEmail->bind_param("sd",$email, $id);
```

TO use the user ID, I have no idea what you call it.  This way when searching for the account, you exclude the current users row from the results.

Your attempt at this query (in the updated question)

> $stmtEmail = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND id_user NOT IN (?)");
>
> $stmtEmail->bind_param("ss",$email,$email);

Is bound to fail, because you have `$email,$email` isntead of `$email,$id`

Also when using `NOT IN()` you generally have to assign the array elements separately.  Instead of `NOT IN(?)` you need `IN(?,?,?)`.  At least as far as I know, I don't use Mysqli.  It also makes no sense to check an array, as you have one user logged in and therefor should only exclude them.

Comment: edit my question again, the problem is not where it indicates, do not add the rest because that is not the problem.

Comment: If you don't add all the code you should indicate that by  a comment or putting something like `// ... other code here`  Or something because when you say, Before the edit, some thing like `If user enters name ..., then it doesn't update` etc.

Comment: I have already added it, but the problem is up in the first query

Comment: Yea because you are not using the current users ID, and then when you do, you use the email, and assuming that is an array , because you use `IN` as far as I know you can't bind an array to a single placeholder.  If it's not an array you should not use `IN` but `=` instead.

Comment: Pet peeve, naming conventions. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check all emails in database where **user_id is NOT equal to this email id** provided..And if new email id for this user_id does not exist in  database for other than this user_id, then and then only update email...also send another email verification link with new email id to this user to verify and make him logout from current session....

e.g.

```
if ($stmtEmail->num_rows>0) { //**query should be for email check where user_id != this user_id**
    echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["email" =>"The user with this email already exists!"]]);
    exit;
} else {
    $stmtUpAccounts = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET first_name=?, last_name=?, phone=?, country=?, city=?, state=?, address=?, zip_code=?, email=? WHERE id_user=?");
   //** Add send email code to send new email verification code link to this new email...
}
```

Because

```
if ($stmtEmail->num_rows>0) {
```

this single line will not resolve your issue.... You need to check `num_rows > 0` where `user_id != this_user_id`....

Comment: I do not understand the procedure of your answer :(